# Desktop & mobile Css browers

Tags: css, mobile, web, desktop

I Set up A Desktop & mobile Css, I put the Desktop on index.html and the mobile on m.index.html but the Desktop is coming up on both Desktop/laptop and mobile.How can I get the mobile to work

can somebody help me with the code

Comment: Please post the code you currently have, as it difficult for us to conjure code on-the-fly. Thanks.

Comment: remove the trailing `/` after `m.index.html`

And so other people can read this easier, please comment under my answer so everything gets grouped together better :)

Comment: @MikeKoch android works Iphone Page not found

Comment: Works fine for me on iOS 5.1.1. Try clearing your iPhone's cache and try again.

Comment: @MikeKoch Thank you sir, I been trying to get that the last 3day

Comment: If the script worked, please either upvote or mark the answer as "accepted" so other users with the same question can easily see an accepted solution

Answer (score 0):

Since `index.html` is the default page *any* browser is going to go to (as it is set as the default page for a directory), you will have to add the following JavaScript to your `index.html` page to redirect mobile users to the `m.index.html` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (screen.width<800) {
  window.location="http://yourdomain.com/mobile/";
  }
</script>
```